# Building Boost 1.53.0 Boost Log 2.0r862 on OSX 10.8.3

Tags: boost, osx-mountain-lion, undefined-reference, boost-log

I am working at building Boost 1.53.0 with Boost Log 2.0r862 on Mac OSX 10.8.2 and installed it to a fake root to keep the /usr/lib* and /opt/lib* clean. I built and installed Boost with
`./bootstrap --prefix=/path/to/myfakerootdir`
and installed the library with
`./b2 install` 
 
This built and installed successfully; when running cmake on my project it properly detects the library include and lib directory. Yet after it completes building and attempts to run the executable I get

`dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/brad/dev/strata/strataextract/build/Debug/StrataExtractUnitTests
  Reason: image not found`

Some the possible issues I've researched include:

1.Using otool to change the executable manually (Though it seems like a very "hacky" solution)

2.Use a modified portfile at [Github Macports Overlay](https://github.com/mavam/macports-overlay) (Though the current version offered is too old for my project.

3.Multiple build tutorials on Boost, unfortunately most referencing Bjam which from what I 
understand is no longer good practice. 

I seem to remember of a similar situation requiring me to set relative path to false, but I am unsure how I would do this with Boost + bjam.

Comment: You're linking boost dynamically - is it intentional? Does `libboost_system.dylib` exist and where?

Comment: Yes it exists in /path/to/myfakerootdir/lib/

Comment: I have found that if I copy the dylib in the same directory as teh executable it works. Though the macports copy of Boost (without log) somehow sets the dylib path statically (which is what I would like it to do automatically)

Comment: Does the following help? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#select-a-build-directory

Comment: I read through it and I got the libraries built, it seems that the best solution maybe if I could somehow get boost from macports and build Boost log from macports

Comment: I have gotten much closer by adding the <code>#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK</code> the only error I get is <code>libboost_log.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option::enum_type, boost::system::error_code*)'
</code>